# I thought ajax was same orgin policy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm confused about the same domain orgin policy with jquery ajax. If i make a get request to a url with jquery, I can get the results back. What am I missing? I thought it was restricted to same orgin policy.

```
    $(function () {
        var data;                     

      var x =   $.ajax({

            dataType: 'json', 
            url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', 
            data: data, 
            success: function(){ console.log("true");}, 
            failure: function(){console.log("failed");}
        });


      console.log(x);

    });
```

Comment: The given domain allows [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Yes, it is. Although, you can configure your website to [allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Relaxing_the_same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 3):

See [this page](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

> API can be accessed from your development environment through CORS or JSONP.

Yes, it is, but the website you are requesting specifically allows [CORS (cross-origin resource sharing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) as well as [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) requests, meaning you can request the data from another origin using either one of those methods. Using the `.ajax()` method with `dataType: 'json'` means you are using CORS. You could also make a JSONP request with `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

Both CORS and JSONP are specific server options that can be enabled to allow users to request data from another origin. Keep in mind that the data could be modified on the server to be malicious, so it could be a potential security hole if you begin using that data. Be sure to only use CORS or JSONP with a service you trust.

Comment: It might be nitpicky and changing the wording might make it harder to understand, so it is just a note: CORS / JSONP do not enable the _requesting_ of the data, but allow the client to get access to the requested data. You can always load external resources like js, images, css, ... files into your page, otherwise JSONP and CDN would not work. But per default the client would not be allowed to read the content of those files.

Comment: Isn't it up to the browser to allow or disallow `CORS`? If it was up to the website, then can't any spam hacker website "allow CORS" and steal your information?

Comment: @Imray [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). If a user visits server `A` with browser `B`, and a CORS request is sent to server `C`, browser `B` has to implement CORS but it doesn't really make any decisions, and server `C` has to decide to allow the request or not. `C` sends a specific header in the response saying that site `A` is allowed to make CORS requests to `C`. If that header doesn't match, then browser `B` doesn't allow the webpage to receive the requested content.

Comment: @Adam so `C` has to maintain a list of all the websites in the world that it allows to make requests from it?

Comment: @Imray, read the link in my last comment. Wildcards are allowed, so server `C` returning the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` would allow any website to make CORS requests to it.